# Writing a PHP-based tool - should I use a framework?

Tags: codeigniter, php

I am making a very specific "control panel" sort of thing to organize information, record statistics, deliver alerts, and things like that.

My initial plan was to make it using CakePHP. I tried Cake, and although I thought it was really awesome, I really hated it due to the fact that it's "automagic." I didn't like how it did all this stuff without me knowing. Yesterday I switched to CodeIgniter, because a friend told me to try it. I like CI much better, however using a PHP framework just doesn't feel right. To me, it doesn't feel nearly free or flexible enough.

**My question to you:**
Should I continue trying to use a framework, or should I construct a 'semi-framework' that makes certain things easier (layouts, form validation, localization)?

Might I add that I already have a secure authentication system created (well, I THINK it's secure, but that's for a different discussion :P)  that would be fairly simple to implement on this site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use a framework or write my own MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901788/should-i-use-a-framework-or-write-my-own-mvc)

Comment: @michael Perhaps (I'm agreeing here and flagging it myself), though I'd like to point out that all frameworks are not MVC frameworks, even with PHP. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I continue trying to use a framework, or should I construct a
>   'semi-framework' that makes certain things easier (layouts, form
>   validation, localization)?

I think the big issue here is **whether using a framework is making your life easier or not.** Frameworks are designed to simplify coding by giving you a powerful base to work off of in your own code. If that base is helping you by reducing the amount of code you need to write and the amount of maintenance that goes into it, then yes, I would strongly recommend you use a framework. If the framework is making your job more difficult because it is not well suited to your needs and is not reducing the amount of work you need to do overall, then I would strongly recommend not wasting your time with one.

Just like you'd stop using a dishwasher that isn't helping you wash the dishes faster or better, go ahead and stop using a framework that isn't helping you *code* faster or better.

Comment: That really makes sense, but there's a small problem: I really don't know if it is any better. In a recent project, I separated my PHP into  three places: 'includes' (where I get common files), 'root' (my site root, pages that the user sees) and 'ajax' (files that handle ajax requests). Is that better? Perhaps, if I made a few additions to better streamline the process.

Comment: Is it easy for you to understand? Has the 'magic' in the code been removed so that you feel comfortable going in to make changes and fix problems without fear of breaking said magic? If it has, then you're probably doing the right thing, because magic code is bad code in that it is difficult to improve and adapt since you don't fully understand it. If you've removed that magic and now fully understand the code, I would definitely say that you've improved your odds for success. (sorry if I'm insulting your intelligence by giving you such basic answers...)

Comment: no no, it's fine. Yes, it's very easy to understand, an it gets the job done. I like your answer. thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your site. If you have large site with dozens of pages, better use a framework. But if your site is tiny, there is no need in using it.

Answer (score -1):

Try combining Zend with NuSphere PHPEd IDE. Zend is a generic all-purpose framework which allows you to go as hardcore as you desire and it has tons of examples and documentation. PHPEd will enable you to do really nice debugging, even inside the framework code, so that you will feel in absolute control.

On the other hand, reinventing the wheel is never a good idea. You will never be able to get all the form validations right all by yourself and the amount of testing for all this code will make you stay in the office, on Tuesdays, during the graveyard shift :)

It might be a great idea to spend some time reading about some open-source projects, like [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/), so that you can observe the true power of generic frameworks, before trying to write your own.

Comment: Hm.. Like I said, I wouldn't be writing a whole framework, but rather a 'semi-framework' Essentially a few files just to make my life easier.

Comment: @DrAgonmoray I don't see the harm in doing so as long as you know what you're doing and can avoid most (or all) of the common gotchas. Just don't reinvent the wheel for big stuff if you don't have to.

Comment: Well, I used to create a wrapper class for executing SQL statements and then several files filled with SQL statements for each "model" class. Thus, I ended up repeating tons of code and changing stuff was a nightmare. Afterwards, I learned about ORM (Object Relational Mapping) and the power of EAV databases. Ask yourself if you can design, implement and test a generic framework that is able to build SQL statements automagically based on the ORM doctrine all by yourself. If the answer is yes, then you must have a lot of free time...

Comment: But is that really something that I need? (i know it isn't something that i particularly want)

Comment: Depends on if you want something that heavy.  There's lighter alternatives out there to doctrine anyways (that big pile of bloat is nasty to work with, bleh) - redbean is worth a shot for something flexible.

Comment: It was just an example from my own painful experience with refusing to use frameworks, but it applies in many other places. If you will have huge forms with tons of fields and database interaction, just imagine that the client will ask you to change 20% of the functionality. You will be pulling hairs out and growing white ones instead. This is why I always recommend doing things as generic as possible, when it comes to web development, even for small projects. By the way, SQL injection will always bite you when you least expect it, even if you think it can never happen to your site :)

Comment: Also, downvoted because blind evangelical adherence to frameworks leads to unhappy servers.  Try profiling some of them and seeing how heavy they actually are; a good one to make your skin crawl would be Symfony's YAML parser, even.  Ripping that dependency out of my own projects ended up cutting page gen times to a third of what they were, all because some regex-happy nut thought it'd be fun to run multiple regexps in a loop for a single file (and I was loading from three files!)